# jQuery.noConflict() fix not working when using jQuery with prototype.js

Tags: prototypejs, javascript, jquery

Asked a question earlier and got a fantastic response, you guys are amazing. The question now is how to properly implement the solution.

I'm attempting to use jQuery and prototype libraries with each other, using the jQuery.noConfict() fix:

```
<script src="./js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>

     jQuery.noConflict();

  // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("slideshow1").hide();
 });

 // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
 $('#lightbox').hide();
   </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/scriptaculous.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.lite.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#slideshow1').cycle({
        delay: 2000,
        speed: 1000,
    });


});

</script>
```

I understand the principle (that by default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"), and the solution to this looks like it should work. However, when implemented the page comes up as a blank background.

[This is a demo of the page, using the current script implementation.](http://www.abyy.net)

How would one fix this?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? E.g. what error indications exist? What error(s), if any, does the page have? Don't guess randomly -- the computer is behaving very deterministically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one thing, you're linking `prototype.js` improperly. It should be `./js/prototype.js`.

**Edit**
Also missing a few others: ./js/dragdrop.js ./js/controls.js ./js/slider.js

Then, it looks like you're using jQuery not prototype (though, I don't have any experience with prototype). I looked it up on their site and you pass the id into the `$()` function, not a css-like/jQuery selector. So where you have `$("#slideshow1").hide();`, you have to make it `jQuery("#slideshow1").hide();` or `$("slideshow1").hide();` if it's a prototype function. This goes the same for other scripts down the page.

**Edit 2**
After you fix the missing JavaScript files, this line: `$('slideshow1').hide();` should be `jQuery('#slideshow1').hide();`.

And these:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow1').cycle({
        delay: 2000,
        speed: 1000,
    });
});
```

Should be:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#slideshow1').cycle({
        delay: 2000,
        speed: 1000,
    });
});
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Fixed, but the problem persists.

Comment: @WednesdayWolf - There are a few other missing files as well: ./js/dragdrop.js   ./js/controls.js    ./js/slider.js

Comment: I'm using jQuery for the cycle: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/ and prototype for the lightbox. I just realized I wasn't associating the id's to the correct libraries. So the new secondary library association is: $("#slideshow1").hide(); $("lightbox").hide(); However, this breaks the slideshow.

Comment: @WednesdayWolf - You're close, the first one is jQuery, so you need to reference it by `jQuery()` not by `$()`.

Comment: @Drackir - You beautiful, glorious bastard. Thank you so much; the fixes worked like a charm.

Comment: When I make the changes I mentioned above, the background scrolls through images. Is that what's intended?

Comment: Oh and those missing files I was referring to are loaded dynamically from scriptaculous.js. You should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I think Prototype does $(id), not $(selector) as jQuery does. Also it returns the actual DOM element. So e.g. `$('#slideshow1').hide()` would be, in Prototype, `$('slideshow1').style.visibility = 'hidden'`, I believe. For such things, jQuery is going to be easier. It looks as though all your $() calls are really jQuery() calls and would need rewriting to the Prototype way to work - or just change $ to jQuery.

**Edit:** actually, that $ isn't even Prototype... Prototype is `$$`.

Comment: Interesting. Changed $('#slideshow1').hide() to $('slideshow1').style.visibility = 'hidden', but it didn't fix the problem. The solution I'm working with is taking a page directly from the JQuery documentation, which uses prototype as its example. http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function

Comment: $ is prototype as well but it's short for selecting IDs. $$ allows you to use CSS-style selectors as with jQuery.